How to install php-memcached ext on php 7.4
I have upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 24.04 and i have several versions of php installed on my server
sudo update-alternatives --config php

So the problem is that i cant install php-memcached on php7.4 version
I tried
apt install php7.4-memcached
but it gives error
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-memcached E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-memcached'
After this, i tried
apt install php-memcached
apt-cache search memcached | grep PHP

gives this:

The problem is that it is installing memcached extension only for php 8.3
How to force php-memcached to install for PHP 7.3 ?

This might be a better fit for superuser.com, but try apt-cache search memcached | grep php to see what options you have available

Are you using the ondrej/sury PPA to get PHP 7.4?

StackOverflow is primarily for programming questions. If you don't get an answer, try https://askubuntu.com/

apt install php7.4-memcache  solved it for me (note no trailing letter d)

I presume you're probably using the ondrej/sury PPA, which does not include pre-compiled versions of the memcached module for 24.04 Noble. So, you'll have to compile it yourself. As root:
pecl install memcached
echo "extension=memcached.so" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/memcached.ini 
phpenmod -v 7.4 memcached

If you want to then also install it for other PHP versions, you'll need to first remove the PECL registry so it doesn't think it's already installed:
rm /usr/share/php/.registry/.channel.pecl.php.net/memcached.reg


Thank you! Additionally, for compilation apt install libmemcached-dev is required

You need to carefully read the error messages you have got and then fix them one by one to be able to compile, it's not difficult, good luck!
